# Calling function, from callback stored in object, in an array

Tags: javascript, canvas

basically all I want to do is be able to call a function referenced in an object, for whatever reason i'm having major trouble, the error on chrome is : 
`Uncaught TypeError: obj.draw is not a functionrender @ main.js:46main @ main.js:16` maybe this means it's private? I'm not sure, anyway's here's a MVCE

```
var bullets = [];
bullets.push(bullet)

;(function() // I know this is a little overkill for an mvce
{
  function main()
  {
    window.requestAnimationFrame( main );
    render();
  }
  main();
})();

function bullet()
{
  this.x = canvas.width/2;
  this.y = canvas.height/2;
  this.move = function()
  {
    ++this.y;
  };
  this.draw = function()
  {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, 5, 10);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
  };
}


function render()
{
  for( let obj of bullets )
      obj.draw();
}
```

Comment: Try to change the `let` with `var`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar `for( let obj of bullets )`, it holds a ref to each bullet, as the loop iterates through.

Comment: Yea yea... Got that, sorry. Didn't notice it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pushing a class, but invoking an object's function. Here `bullet` is a class and not an instantiation of it. Only the instantiated variables will have the function. Change your code to:

```
bullets.push(new bullet());
```

And put the function declaration to the top. (Not necessary).

```js
var bullets = [];
bullets.push(new bullet())

;(function() // I know this is a little overkill for an mvce
{
  function main()
  {
    window.requestAnimationFrame( main );
    render();
  }
  main();
})();

function bullet()
{
  this.x = canvas.width/2;
  this.y = canvas.height/2;
  this.move = function()
  {
    ++this.y;
  };
  this.draw = function()
  {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, 5, 10);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
  };
}


function render()
{
  for( let obj of bullets )
      obj.draw();
}
```

The above code throws `canvas` isn't defined, which is expected for the snippet. Hope this helps.